# Missalignment with inline-block (other elements pushed down)

Tags: html, css, row, offset

I'm trying to align small boxes in a row. These boxes have something like 2 elements in each. In some cases, the first element is so "much" text, that it splits into 2 lines. If this happens, all other blocks in this special line are shown below.

Long story short, here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PMRQ5/

If you resize the HTML field, you can see what I mean. Can somebody help?

```css
.songlist .even {
  background: #c2e4fa;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9eefc, #c2e4fa);
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.songlist .odd {
  background: #faf4c2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcf8d9, #faf4c2);
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.songlist .itemBox {
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 220px;
  min-height: 100px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.songlist .itemBox .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.songlist .itemBox .artist {
  clear: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.songlist .itemBox .titlerating {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
.songlist .itemBox .dance {
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='songlist'>
  <div class='itemBox even'>
    <div class='cover'></div>
    <div class='title'>You and you</div>
    <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='itemBox odd'>
    <div class='title'>The Queen's lace hankerchief waltz</div>
    <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='itemBox even'>
    <div class='cover'></div>
    <div class='title'>Voices of spring</div>
    <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='itemBox odd'>
    <div class='cover'></div>
    <div class='title'>Roses from the south</div>
    <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gah, it seems you're using a strange mix of values to get this effect. What exactly is your desired outcome? The "moving of elements" is standard when using inline-block. Do you want them to never move from the top line when the window is resized?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PMRQ5/1/

Add `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: bottom` to the box, depends on what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much - this was the solution :)

Comment: doesn't work... you need to add `vertical-align: top` to the element you're trying to fix, not to the container

Comment: This works, but why does it happen in the first place if the boxes are exactly the same size as each other?

Comment: @kajow7 In case you're still wondering... Because an inline-block doesn't behave like a block. It acts a bit like an inline element. The default alignment of the inline-block is "baseline" which is a bit unpredictable. Full specification and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Could you add the relevant code here instead of just in the JS fiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.songlist .even {
  background:#c2e4fa;
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#d9eefc,#c2e4fa);
  margin-right:5px;
}
.songlist .odd {
  background:#faf4c2;
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fcf8d9,#faf4c2);
  margin-right:5px;
}
.songlist .itemBox {
  font-size:11px;
  width:220px;
  min-height:100px;
  clear:both;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px 10px 5px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:4px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.songlist .itemBox .title {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
}
.songlist .itemBox .artist {
  clear:left;
  font-size:11px;
}
.songlist .itemBox .titlerating {
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
  position:absolute;
}
.songlist .itemBox .dance {
  bottom:5px;
  right:10px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='songlist'>
    <div class='itemBox even'>
        <div class='cover'></div>        
        <div class='title'>You and you</div>
        <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>        
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>                    
    <div class='itemBox odd'>    
        <div class='title'>The Queen's lace hankerchief waltz</div>
        <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>        
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='itemBox even'>
        <div class='cover'></div>    
        <div class='title'>Voices of spring</div>
        <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>    
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>                    
    <div class='itemBox odd'>
        <div class='cover'></div>        
        <div class='title'>Roses from the south</div>
        <div class='artist'>101 Strings Orchestra</div>    
    <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```